# Is there an API for real time token values?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, api, exchange-api

This is not a coding question so if this is the wrong place to ask it please advice where I can ask it.
I am looking for an API where I can get real time token values both on Sepolia and then also on Main net on Uniswap, PancakeSwap and as many DEXes as possible.

Comment: hey if you are looking for a third party service to get the values of token on mainnet, you can try coingecko and coinmarketcap, but i don't think testnet tokens are supported.